# Child Plugin Admin Panel

Tags: plugins, customization, wp-admin

So I've installed wp-mail-bank plugin and I want to customize certain part of them core. So I choose to use Hooks :

location :    /wp-mail-bank.php

[image]

```
function backend_plugin_css_scripts_mail_bank()
    {
        wp_enqueue_style("framework.css", plugins_url("/assets/css/framework.css",__FILE__));
        wp_enqueue_style("wp-mail-bank.css", plugins_url("/assets/css/wp-mail-bank.css",__FILE__));
    }
add_action("admin_init","backend_plugin_css_scripts_mail_bank");
```

So I just want create a plugin who replace this function with remove_action like :

```
function dzaok_backend_plugin_css_scripts_mail_bank()
    {
        wp_enqueue_style("framework.css", plugins_url("/framework.css",__FILE__));
        wp_enqueue_style("wp-mail-bank.css", /dzaok-mail.css",__FILE__));
    }
add_action("admin_init","dzaok_backend_plugin_css_scripts_mail_bank");
```

And for information this plugin is used in /wp-admin/

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're asking how to remove the first action, which the plugin has created?

Removing an action is really easy - all you need to do is call `remove_action` like this:

`remove_action("admin_init", "backend_plugin_css_scripts_mail_bank");`

Then add your replacement action.

You need to ensure that you remove the action after it has been added (because otherwise there's nothing to remove!) and before the admin_init hook runs (otherwise the action you wanted to remove would have already run). For further information on which hooks run in which order, you can see https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference (or Google for another appropriate reference).

Comment: Thanks I'll see that tomorrow and just where I've to put the functions.php in my template or in a new plugin who's activated ? Thanks a lot to help me [^^]

Comment: You're welcome :) You should be able to put it in either your functions.php or in a plugin you're creating, the key is just to make sure it runs at the right time. Where you put it probably depends more on the purpose of this site: are you creating your own theme from scratch? Are you likely to change to a different theme in the future? If the latter is true, you might be better off creating your own plugin so you don't have to re-add this code (and also, if you're using a theme from elsewhere, you wouldn't want your code to be overridden when you update it!)

Comment: How did you go with this @Acrodeminecraft?